# vector math in unity to avoid obstacles

Tags: unity-game-engine, path-finding

I am trying to make my character to avoid obstacles while moving.

the target is defined on click and character moves to it on every frame by updating transform.position (so no physics here).

every obstacle has collider and character has trigger. on TriggerStay event of the character I have managed to get some info about the contact point:

```
Vector3 point = other.ClosestPointOnBounds(transform.position);
Vector3 dist = point - transform.position;
```

and the best thing I came to is to:

```
Vector3 perp = Vector3.Cross(transform.forward, dist.normalized);
float dir = Vector3.Dot(perp, transform.up);

transform.position -= transform.right * dir;
```

but it does not work as I was expected. actually it does not work at all.
how to correct character position, So it appears to be smoothly deflected of obstacle, while moving to the target?

EDIT: here is the screenshot

[image: screenshot]

white rays show the direction of contacts, so they are multiple.
what i want is that the character can avoid obstacles while moving to his target.

for now i came to new idea:

```
float correction = Vector3.Dot(transform.right, dist.normalized) / 10;
transform.position += transform.right * correction;
```

it somewhat works as i want, but character is constantly jumping from one place to another. don't know how to fix this.

also tried correcting direction of movement by substracting the vector of contact from vector of movement, but character is also moves jerky and rotates stupidly.

Comment: Do ypu cinsider using nav mesh agent?

Comment: i have randomly generated levels, so would be harder generating navmesh on the fly

Comment: Maybe cast a ray of a certain length and when you find an obstacle then move your character perpendicular to your ray until the ray is not obstructed?

Comment: the thing is that this normal to the ray may push character to the wall instead, depending on the side where this ray was casted. i'm not very good at vector math, that's why i've asked for help

Comment: A screenshot of your level with the character and obstacles and/or a description of your game would really help. Because there are multiple ways to solve the problem that you have asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
Vector3 perp = Vector3.Cross(transform.forward, other.transform.up);
transform.position -= perp.normalized * other.bounds.size.x / 2f;
```

You seem to not use Vector3.Cross proper way. Read here about it: [Unity3D docs link](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Cross.html)